# Is there a way to connect ellipses with a line on WPF C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this assignment where I must write an interactive program where the user clicks the screen and puts a dot at the spot of his mouse click and then when he puts a second dot they must connect with a line.

```
<Window x:Class="courseWorkOOP.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:courseWorkOOP"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Практикум ООП" Height="600" Width="800">
<Grid x:Name="myGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    
    <Canvas Name="myCanvas" Height="480" Width="640" MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown_1" MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove_1">
        <Canvas.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0"/>
        </Canvas.Background>
    </Canvas>
    <Button Click="btn_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="200" Content="Clear"/>
    <!--<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Button Name="btn" Click="btn_Click">Clear</Button>
    </StackPanel>-->
    
</Grid>
```

This is my XAML

```
 private void Canvas_MouseDown_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        
        if (e.ButtonState == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            currentPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
            Ellipse currDot = new Ellipse() { Width = 10, Height = 10,Fill=Brushes.Black };
            myCanvas.Children.Add(currDot);
            Canvas.SetLeft(currDot, e.GetPosition(this).X);
            Canvas.SetTop(currDot, e.GetPosition(this).Y);
            double coordinateX = Canvas.GetLeft(currDot);
            double coordinateY = Canvas.GetTop(currDot);
            Line myLine = new Line() { X1 = coordinateX, Y1 = coordinateY,X2=coordinateY,Y2=coordinateX,Stroke=Brushes.Green,StrokeThickness=4 };
            myCanvas.Children.Add(myLine);
        }
    }
    private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myCanvas.Children.Clear();
    }

    private void Canvas_MouseMove_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        //{
        //    Line line = new Line();
        //    line.Stroke = SystemColors.WindowFrameBrush;
        //    line.StrokeThickness = 20;
        //    line.X1 = currentPoint.X;
        //    line.Y1 = currentPoint.Y;
        //    line.X2 = e.GetPosition(this).X;
        //    line.Y2 = e.GetPosition(this).Y;

        //    currentPoint = e.GetPosition(this);

        //    myCanvas.Children.Add(line);
        //}
    }
```

And this is the C# part.

My question is how do I get two dots to connect with a line?

I've tried `ClickCount` but it did nothing, I might've used it incorrectly.
Before that I've tried initializing an integer value inside `Canvas_MouseDown_1` and then made an If statement that basically said draw a line between this and that every two clicks but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to connect the dots with a line, you need to keep track of the previous click point, so that you can connect the "currentPoint" to the "previousPoint".  You also need a flag to only create the line once you have *at least* one point on the canvas.

```
private Point previousPoint;
private Point currentPoint;
private bool hasPoints;

private void Canvas_MouseDown_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.ButtonState == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        previousPoint = currentPoint;
        currentPoint = e.GetPosition(this.myCanvas);
        currentPoint.X -= 5; // Use 5, which is half the width/height of the dot
        currentPoint.Y -= 5; // Use 5, which is half the width/height of the dot
        Ellipse currDot = new Ellipse() { Width = 10, Height = 10, Fill = Brushes.Black };
        myCanvas.Children.Add(currDot);
        Canvas.SetLeft(currDot, currentPoint.X);
        Canvas.SetTop(currDot, currentPoint.Y);
        if (hasPoints)
        {
            // Add 4 to the line position, due to the stroke thickness being 4
            Line myLine = new Line() { X1 = previousPoint.X + 4, Y1 = previousPoint.Y + 4, X2 = currentPoint.X + 4, Y2 = currentPoint.Y + 4, Stroke = Brushes.Green, StrokeThickness = 4 };
            myCanvas.Children.Add(myLine);
        }
        hasPoints = true;
    }
}
```

Example output:
[image]

**EDITED AFTER COMMENT BELOW:** If you want every two dots connecting, just make this simple logical change:

```
if (hasPoints)
{
    // Add 4 to the line position...
    Line myLine = new Line() { X1 ...
    myCanvas.Children.Add(myLine);
    hasPoints = false;
}
else
{
    hasPoints = true;
}
```

Output from above code:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fundamentally wrong. Before writing a WPF program you should study [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf), and especially [the data binding section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-binding-overview). Unfortunately, the Microsoft-provided documentation isn't super great, so you should also read what you can find here and elsewhere on the web about the primary design pattern used for WPF programs, MVVM.

If you follow the MVVM pattern, your program will be simpler to write and simpler to understand, because you won't be struggling to figure out all your UI interactions at the same time that you're also struggling to figure out all the underlying data. MVVM separates these concerns ("separation of concerns" being one of the most important software practices in any context). Here is an example of what that might look like for your example…

First, you know you will have two kinds of graphical objects, so create models for those:

```cs
class CanvasItemViewModel
{
    public Point Location { get; }

    public CanvasItemViewModel(Point location)
    {
        Location = location;
    }
}

class PointViewModel : CanvasItemViewModel
{
    public PointViewModel(Point location) : base(location) { }
}

class LineViewModel : CanvasItemViewModel
{
    public double X2 { get; }
    public double Y2 { get; }

    public LineViewModel(PointViewModel start, PointViewModel end) : base(start.Location)
    {
        X2 = end.Location.X - start.Location.X;
        Y2 = end.Location.Y - start.Location.Y;
    }
}
```

In this case, I know ahead of time that I'm going to want to be able to treat points and lines the same, when it comes to positioning them in the canvas, so I use a common base class to represent where on the canvas they will be.

Since the line will be positioned via its `Location` property, I can leave the `X1` and `Y1` properties out, and just set the `X2` and `Y2`, based on the points the line will connect.

With these elements taken care of, now I need a way to manage the points and lines. That looks like this:

```cs
class MainViewModel
{
    public CompositeCollection CanvasItems { get; } = new CompositeCollection();

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        CanvasItems.Add(new CollectionContainer { Collection = _lines });
        CanvasItems.Add(new CollectionContainer { Collection = _points });
    }

    private readonly ObservableCollection<PointViewModel> _points = new ObservableCollection<PointViewModel>();
    private readonly ObservableCollection<LineViewModel> _lines = new ObservableCollection<LineViewModel>();

    public void AddPoint(Point point)
    {
        PointViewModel pointModel = new PointViewModel(point);

        _points.Add(pointModel);

        if (_points.Count > 1)
        {
            _lines.Add(new LineViewModel(_points[_points.Count - 2], pointModel));
        }
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _points.Clear();
        _lines.Clear();
    }
}
```

Here again, I know that I want to display the points and lines in the same control, so the collections are combined into a single `CompositeCollection` for the benefit of the canvas that will be displaying them. I maintain two separate collections though, to make it easier to manage the collections in the model code.

The line collection is included first in the composite collection, so that the points will draw on top of the lines. Of course, if you want to see the entire line on top of the points, you would simply swap the order of the two collections in the composite collection.

Observable collections are used because the collection contents will be changing based on user input, and this allows WPF to be notified and respond as needed automatically, without additional work on your part. I.e. this is a fundamental aspect of data binding (along with implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`, something that's not actually necessary in this example, but which is used heavily in a typical WPF program).

The model code itself does nothing but add points and lines to the collection when necessary, and provide a means to clear both collections.

Note that up to this point, there's *nothing* that is really dependent on the UI. The classes do use the WPF `Point` and `CompositeCollection` types, but this is mainly out of convenience. The implementation isn't really inherently tied to WPF, and those could be abstracted out relatively easily.

With all the basic data structures defined, *now* is the time to shift the focus to the UI, starting with the XAML:

```xml
<Window x:Class="TestSO66159694ClickPointsAndLines.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TestSO66159694ClickPointsAndLines"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
      <!-- The templates will rely on the ItemsControl to correctly position them -->
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:PointViewModel}">
        <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Black">
          <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            <!-- Center the ellipse on its actual location -->
            <TranslateTransform X="-5" Y="-5"/>
          </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        </Ellipse>
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:LineViewModel}">
        <Line Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="4"              
              X2="{Binding X2}" Y2="{Binding Y2}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CanvasItems}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <Canvas IsItemsHost="True" MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown_1">
            <Canvas.Background>
              <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0"/>
            </Canvas.Background>
          </Canvas>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
          <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Location.X}"/>
          <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Location.Y}"/>
        </Style>
      </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
    <Button Click="btn_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="200" Content="Clear"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

This XAML has two main sections to it: the templates corresponding to the graphical elements, which give the actual visual representation for these; and the actual content of the window, which handles binding the collection and setting the event handlers for the user interface (i.e. mouse-down and button-click).

WPF will automatically find the template appropriate for each graphical element. The actual positioning of the element within the canvas is provided by the `ItemContainerStyle`; this is because an `ItemsControl` will wrap your actual content in a presenter which is the actual direct child of the canvas, for which the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties apply.

The canvas itself is provided as the `ItemsPanelTemplate` for the `ItemsControl` object. The default for `ItemsControl` is `StackPanel`, but you can provide any panel template you want to customize the behavior.

Finally, there is the actual user input. With all of the ground-work done above, this is really simple:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly MainViewModel _mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = _mainViewModel;
    }

    private void Canvas_MouseDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        IInputElement canvas = sender as IInputElement;
        Point canvasLocation = e.GetPosition(canvas);

        _mainViewModel.AddPoint(canvasLocation);
    }

    private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _mainViewModel.Clear();
    }
}
```

Since the main view model object has all the real data management logic, all the view itself (i.e. the window) needs to do is get the mouse position and pass that along to the main view model to deal with. Likewise, clearing the list is delegated to the main view model as well.

The *view* itself knows *nothing* about the underlying data structures, nor should it. The view's job is to provide the layer in your problem that interacts directly with the user, presenting to the user the underlying data in a form that is useful and comprehensible to the user, and taking user input and passing that along to the underlying data structures so that it can accomplish whatever it needs to do.

In addition to simplifying the overall design of the program, and making it easier to think about each discrete function of the program separately, doing it this way makes it trivial to adjust the way the visuals are presented to the user, without touching the C# code at all. One just needs to update the templates according to whatever visual aspect is desired.

And of course, when doing things correctly, as above, it's also simple to update the underlying data logic without having to meddle with the view. For example, it turns out your original question was not clear enough and you only want to connect every pair of dots the user clicks, but not make a continuous line. That's an easy enough change, simply by modifying the `AddPoint()` method by adding a single additional condition to the `if` statement that adds the line:

```cs
public void AddPoint(Point point)
{
    PointViewModel pointModel = new PointViewModel(point);

    _points.Add(pointModel);

    if (_points.Count > 1 && _points.Count % 2 == 0)
    {
        _lines.Add(new LineViewModel(_points[_points.Count - 2], pointModel));
    }
}
```

I.e. instead of just checking that there are two or more points with `_points.Count > 1`, also limit adding a line to only when a new pair of points has been added, by including `_points.Count % 2 == 0`. No need for new variables or anything like that. Just take into account the current state of things and act on that.

Note that one of the reasons this change is so easy is that the code above doesn't abuse the user interface API to store the state of your underlying data, and so you have immediate access to the number of points that have been added. This approach would be significantly more challenging if you had to figure out from the state of the UI how many points the user had already added (hence the different approach taken by the other answer, which is to add even more state to the UI to try to keep track of what the user's doing).

Again, good WPF programs always follow the principle of [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Indeed, *any* good program does, but with WPF the framework actually makes it much *easier* to do so, and rewards you when you do. I encourage you to keep that in mind as you continue to learn about programming.